# Showing custom error page if php error occurs in Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

Is there any way in Zend Framework 2 to handle php errors? Specifically, I need to invoke some action if php error occurs or uncaught exception is thrown.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ZF2 view manager you can register default error pages. You can add them to your application `module.config.php` like this:

```
<?php
//module/Application/config/module.config.php

namespace Application;

return array(
    ...

    'view_manager' => array(
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index'
    ),

    ...
)
```

You can decide yourself what the content for those views is.

Read more on the view manager [here in the Zend Framework 2 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.services.html#viewmanager).